# Rails route concerns - Datable routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm wanting to allow several routes to become `:datable`, meaning, they should be filterable by date. Here are my routes:

```
# The datable concern
concern :datable do
  member do
    get 'dated/:start_date/(:end_date)', as: 'dated', constraints: {start_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/, end_date: /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/}
  end
end

# The route in which it's added
resources :applications, concerns: :datable
```

Ideally, this would produce:

```
/applications/1/dated/:start_date/(:end_date)
```

However, I'm getting a routing error:

```
ArgumentError: Missing :action key on routes definition, please check your routes.
```

Obviously I'm missing an `:action` key, but why is this necessary for a concern? Shouldn't it inherit the route in which it's being called?

Comment: What do you mean by "inherit the route? The `resources` route has many actions within it (index, show, new, etc.), how is Rails supposed to know which of those actions it is supposed to use?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. That makes perfect sense. I'll answer myself with how I solved this. Thanks, Matt!

Answer (score 0):

Matt Brictson brought it to my attention that the concern doesn't know which action to route to in the resource. This makes obvious sense, however, I looked over it.

The concern was perfectly fine. To fix the issue I was having, I needed to replace the simple `resources :applications` with the following:

```
# Leave out the index resource, which is what I am "concerning"
resources :applications, except: [:index]

# Manually create the index route; adding the concern.
get 'applications', to: 'applications#index', as: 'applications', concerns: :datable
```

Works like a charm. Thanks for the tip, Matt. I hope this provides insight to someone else with this problem.